# Macro causing linker errors

Tags: c++, macros, linker-errors

I have a bunch of macros defined in a library for example called `MY_LIB.so` I built and compiled  it successfully. Example:

```
#define DOSOMETHING() function()

#define ANOTHER() function2()
```

When I use it in another project, I linked it in my Makefile using `-lMY_LIB` and I am getting an undefined reference error to function(). I click on it and it brings me to `DOSOMETHING()` macro. How do I get around with linker errors from macros?

Comment: Macros in a library ".so" file !!!!!!! macros are dead after preprocessing, after then no trace of them remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Macro` is nothing more than just a copy of it content to code. The `linker` sais that `function` is not implemented. So just provide an implentation